# Is it possible for a trojan app to keep plaguing an iOS device after the app had been uninstalled?

Tags: iphone, applications, security, malware

An app that comes with AceDeceiver got installed invisibly against my will on my iPhone, iOS ver. 15.6.

Full background analysis by PaloAltoNetworks:https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/acedeceiver-first-ios-trojan-exploiting-apple-drm-design-flaws-to-infect-any-ios-device/

I have now removed it from my phone, by the looks of it this trojan ware was from 2016 but my device has a system version much older than that, yet it succumbed to this malware.

What I'm trying to find out is how dangerous is this malware after the app has been removed? Should I reset my phone? Will a reset even work to remove the malware?

Would it breach some underlying safety mechanisms and obtain information from other apps, or even passwords? Of course I didn't enter anything into that app. I believe iOS does a decent job in maintaining access control, true?

All in all, how worried should I be?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When in doubt, format!

Your safest course of action will always be to wipe the device and reset to factory. A third party app cannot write to the protected system volume. That said, iOS security is quite robust and uninstalling the app should be sufficient.

#### iOS Security

> What I'm trying to find out is, how dangerous is it after the app has been removed?

[Installed third party apps are “sandboxed”](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/security-of-runtime-process-sec15bfe098e/web) meaning they are isolated from other apps and from modifying the OS. While there are “hooks” that allow applications to access info like contacts, location, etc., it must do so *through iOS*; it cannot do it on its own.

> **Sandboxing**
>
> All third-party apps are “sandboxed,” so they are restricted from accessing files stored by other apps or from making changes to the device. Sandboxing is designed to prevent apps from gathering or modifying information stored by other apps. Each app has a unique home directory for its files, which is randomly assigned when the app is installed. If a third-party app needs to access information other than its own, it does so only by using services explicitly provided by iOS and iPadOS.

Even if the app somehow was able to write code to memory and attempt to execute it whether the app was still installed, iOS employs a security feature on the ARM chip called *Execute Never*.

> Further protection is provided by iOS and iPadOS using ARM’s Execute Never (XN) feature, which marks memory pages as nonexecutable. Memory pages marked as both writable and executable can be used only by apps under tightly controlled conditions: The kernel checks for the presence of the Apple-only dynamic code-signing entitlement. Even then, only a single mmap call can be made to request an executable and writable page, which is given a randomized address. Safari uses this functionality for its JavaScript Just-in-Time (JIT) compiler.

Comment: That's quite reassuring, thank you! Very detailed answer. I wasn't aware of the by default sandbox feature of iOS, now I do.